# nginx redirect from url to another in django admin panel

Tags: python, django, url, nginx, redirect

I would like to have redirect in django admin panel, like this:

```
from
https://url_to_my_page/admin/filer/
to
https://url_to_my_page/admin/filer/folder/
```

I tried to make this on nginx side, but didn't worked:

```
location /admin/filer/ {
    return /admin/filer/folder/;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

For permanent redirect:

```
location /admin/filer/ {
   return 301 /admin/filer/folder/;
}
```

For temporary redirect:

```
location /admin/filer/ {
   return 302 /admin/filer/folder/;
}
```

**Permanent redirect:** tells search engines to update their search results with the new page and remove the old one from its index.

**Temporary redirect:** tells search engines that the page has temporarily moved.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But now I got an error: `my_url_address.com redirected you too many times`. I changed code to: `return 301 http://my_url_address.com/admin/filer/folder/;` without success.

Comment: Have you set name to your `server` block ?  I mean `server_name` ?

Comment: The `server_name` should resemble your domain like `www.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

## views.py

```
def redirect(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("path")
```

## urls.py

```
url("/admin/filer/", redirect)
```

writing with phone, sorry for mustaces

Comment: Please when writing an answer, use proper code formatting. Using a phone is not an excuse, you can also format on the SO mobile app.

Comment: I know you wrote it from your mobile, but it advisable to read the text carefully before posting. I added a few changes to help clarity.